# Watch for the last MongoDB GridFS chunk inserted

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

**Question**

What is a resourceful way to trigger a processing pipeline once as soon as:

- all *GridFS* `fs.chunks` and the `fs.files` entries are available of a newly inserted file?

**Problem**

Using `com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.watch()` on the GridFS collection `fs.files` triggers before the last `fs.chunks` entry of that file is available.

```
ChangeStreamIterable<Document> iterable = collection
                 .watch(Collections.singletonList(
     Aggregates.match(Filters.in("operationType",
                  Collections.singletonList("insert")))));
```

It seems like there is no predefined hook for this problem...

Answer (score 0):

*Based on the [fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) of both collections:*

Watch for *both*, `fs.chunks` and `fs.files` *insert* events and only start processing if:

- `fs.files` insert event ? start if all `fs.chunks` entries exist
- `fs.chunks` insert event ? start if `fs.files` entry exists and this is the *last chunk*:

  ```
  numOfchunks = file.length / file.chunkSize
  isLastChunk = chunk.n == numOfchunks - 1
  ```